# Flutter row alignment

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i would like to have the title exactly in the center of the screen and not the same distance between the other two row children.

Currently I have a row with mainAxisAlignment set to spaceBetween but this is not what I am looking for.

```dart
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 35,
                height: 35,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage("...")),
                    color: Colors.white),
              ),
              const Text(
                "TITLE",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: "IBM",
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              Timer(),
            ],
```

[image]

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to have appBar, use `centerTitle: true,` on appBar.

```dart
appBar: AppBar(
  title: Text("C"),
  centerTitle: true,
  leading: Container(
    width: 35,
    height: 35,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage("...")),
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 24, 11, 11)),
  ),
  actions: [
    CircleAvatar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    ),
  ],
),
```

[image]
While the height is fixed, you can use Stack widget.

```dart
SizedBox(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  height: 35,
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Container(
          width: 35,
          height: 35,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage("...")),
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 24, 11, 11)),
        ),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: const Text(
          "TITLE",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: "IBM",
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 20,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

You can also use Positioned widget to align the items.

Answer (score 0):

To have TITLE centered in this case you should make the right and left Widget having the same width. You can wrap them in a `SizedBox`